# implement vaadin shiro and openDJ (LDAP)

Tags: eclipse, ldap, vaadin, shiro, opendj

I have made a login form with Vaadin 7 by this tutorial:
https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating%20a%20simple%20login%20view.
I have to verify users with my LDAP (openDJ) with shiro.
I have put this into my clickEvent method:

```
Factory<org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager> ldapFactory = new     IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:active.ini");
org.apache.shiro.mgt.SecurityManager sManager = ldapFactory.getInstance();
SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(sManager);

Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {
    UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken("user", "password");
    try {
        currentUser.login(token);
    } catch (UnknownAccountException ex) {
        logger.info("Unknown user");
    } catch (IncorrectCredentialsException ex) {
        logger.info("Incorrect credentials");
    } catch (LockedAccountException ex) {
        logger.info("Account is Locked");
    } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
        logger.info("Authentication Exception");
    }
}

logger.info("User [" + currentUser.getPrincipal() +"] logged succesfully");
currentUser.logout();
```

I have a error on logger and I don't know if this can work? 
I have a active.ini file, and it looks like this:

```
'ldapRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.activedirectory.ActiveDirectoryRealm 
 ldapRealm.url = C:\Users\User\OpenDJ'
```

I searched for a tutorial or example but there isn't one for vaadin shiro and ldap (openDJ).